# Sql Exception 0X80131904 Login failed for user ". The user is not associated with a trusted sql server connection

Tags: sql, winforms, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0

I'm developing a windows application using c# .Net Framework 4.

I have 2 machines; Test and production, connecting to a remote server which has the SQL Server here's my connection string:

```
<add name="MealConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Server=MySQLServer;Database=MEALDB;User Id=Meal;Password=Meal1;Trusted_Connection=True;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`
```

When I run the program from the test machine there's no problem, but when I publish the program and run it from the production machine it gives the error mentioned in the title.

When I remove the trusted connection it gives me a different error: Login failed for user "Meal"
do you have any idea what could be the problem ??

**Latest Update :
I tried the sa Sqlaccount and removed the trusted connection and it worked , when i try the same for the user meal it doesn't work whereas the MEAL suer has the same privileges as the sa account**

Comment: Are you sure that `MySQLServer` machine reference is the same for both Test and Prod, i.e. are those machines on the same network?

Comment: First of all , do you have the same connection string for test and production env ? Second are you able to connect DB from your Production Machine ? Third Is the credential in DB same for production DB ? Forth change the name with IP and port in Server Property if it is not accessable by the instance name.

Comment: @ALex: the test machine is in the domain while the other is not but this is not the case as i have another test machine out of the domain but working perfectly.

Comment: @Sandeep  The connection string it is the same for both machines, I didn't try connecting to the sql server from the production machine.
and yea the credentials are the same in the DB for the prod, and test machines.

Comment: So, if you ping `MySQLServer` from the prod machine, do you get the IP address of the production DB server?

Comment: Yes i do get the IP address when i ping the MySQLServer  from the production DB

Answer (score 0):

I did it I just created a new sql account and gave it a db_owner permission over the database and it worked.